# parse JSON to HTML table: How do I format the css of the table?

Tags: jquery, css, json

I have rendered json data to basic HTML table using [jquery jsontotable][1]

[1]: http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Converting-JSON-Data-To-A-Table-jsonTable.html and it works well. How can I format the css to pick the css of my tables fron the json? Or more still..is there a way of formatting the css of tables that pick up the Json contents? all examples I see only show rendering to basic tables. These are my codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mytableDiv").jsonTable({
        head: ['id', 'notice type', 'description'],
        json: ['id', 'notice_type', 'desc']
    });

    $("#mytableDiv").jsonTableUpdate({
        source: "notice.json",
        rowClass: "rowClass",
        callback: function() {

        }
    });
</script>
```

and the html to render the table is

```
<table id="mytableDiv">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my json file

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "notice_type": "emergency meeting",
        "target": "teachers",
        "post_date": "2014-01-21 09:27:00",
        "closing_date_time": "2014-01-31 00:00:00",
        "description": "Emergency meeting for all to attend",
        "venue": "Head master's office"
    }
]
```

Comment: add css to your tables after your generate your table

Comment: can you please show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have your table already written in the DOM with appropriate ids for each "spot" you want to put data.

Then from your ajax call, just populate the ids:

```
#.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myphpfile.php",
        data: {mydata: mydata},
        dataType : 'json',
        }).done(function(result)
        {
         $('#id').html(result['id']);
         $('#notice_type').html(result['notice_type']);
         $('#target').html(result['target']);
         $('#postdate').html(result['post_date']);       
         $('#closingdatetime').html(result['closing_date_time']);
         $('#description').html(result['description']);
         $('#venue').html(result['venue']);
        });
```

If the table is not already in the DOM, you need to write your .done function to create the table and populate it at the same time.

To style the table, just give in a name/id, and style with CSS in the style section in your header.

---

Edit:
Example table:

```
<table id = 'mytable'>
  <tr>
    <td id='id'></td><td id='notice_type'></td><td id='target'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='postdate'></td><td id='closingdatetime'></td><td id='description'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id='venue'></td><td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
#mytable {
  background-color: red;
}
#mytable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: "To style the table, just give in a name/id, and style with CSS in the style section in your header" :: Kindly explain this

Comment: I've added more to my text above.

Answer (score 0):

To style the table afterwards:

```
$("#mytableDiv td").css(whatever);
$("#mytableDiv th").css(whatever);
```

It's always just a table as far as html and css are concerned, so this will work just fine. What does "format the css to pick the css of my tables from the json" mean? Do you want to pass css values with the json and use them for formatting the table that contains it? This is very unclear.

Comment: I already have css of the table defined but its not picking them

Comment: What does .css(whatever); means? what is whatever?

Comment: whatever is the css you want to apply, whatever it is. so `.css('text-align','right')` for instance, or whatever you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add ***!important*** to your table style.

For example:

```
.mytableDiv { border: 1px solid black !important; }
.notice_type { color: white !important; }
```

In this case, you will override all styles, which apply to the table, tr, td etc...